# Sublime Text 3, GCC build system issue

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext3

When building a working ".c" code file I experience an error building with the menu icons to build(build system GCC)

When I navigate: tools -> build (with GCC selected as build system)

```
'main.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['main.exe']]
[dir: C:\Users\erik\Documents\Carleton University\Sysc 2006\Lab 11\Recursion\Recursion]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Python35-32;C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\erik\AppData\Local\bin\NASM;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\erik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\altera\13.0sp1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;C:\Users\erik\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;]
```

But if i navigate: tools -> command palette -> build with:GCC

```
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Following this beloved visual above I would then navigate: tools -> build (with GCC selected as build system), OR tools -> command palette -> build with:GCC -RUN

```
***Expected working output***
```

This is my GCC.sublime-build file, I suspect this is the file that is causing issues.

```
// Put this file here:
// "C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User"
// Use "Ctrl+B" to Build and "Crtl+Shift+B" to Run the project.
// OR use "Tools -> Build System -> New Build System..." and put the code there.
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],

    // Doesn't work, sublime text 3, Windows 8.1    
    // "cmd" : ["gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}"],

    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",

    // You could add path to your gcc compiler this and don't add path to your "PATH environment variable"
    // "path" : "C:\\MinGW\\bin"

    "variants" : [

        { "name": "Run",
          "cmd" : ["${file_base_name}.exe"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Although the issue may be here, I am very concerned it may also be elsewhere as I have been struggling with implementing libraries.
A second side question would be why is my "Path:" variable so long, is it unnecessarily long? many of those would not be needed in sublime correct?

Comment: Can you call gcc from the command prompt? Do you see main.exe in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes I see a main.exe, it runs this .exe when I use the command palette to build with gcc -RUN. gcc --version outputs the following in command prompt: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to compile and run c++ programs in sublime as well as command prompt also

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[   // to run in the sublime text console
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd":"\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    },
    // to run in the Windows command line
    {
        "name": "Run in cmd",

        "shell_cmd":   "start cmd /k  $file_base_name "

    }
]}
```